# Vue2 and Auth0 error importing Auth0Lock

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, auth0

guys.

I'm working through the official Auth0 and Vue2 authentication tutorial, and getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./utils/auth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'auth0-lock' in 'C:\...\ultimate-startup-battle\utils'
```

My auth.js file has this line, though:

```
import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';
```

I've run 
    npm install auth0-lock --save

and my package.json says it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by reinstalling auth0-lock and restarting the server again.